# How can you manually generate ISO 8601 time python

Tags: python, iso8601

My desired output is something like this in ISO 8601 format:
Is there a way I just manually written it like that? Thank you!

```html
2012-11-03T18:15:00-08:00
2012-11-03T18:30:00-08:00
2012-11-03T18:45:00-08:00
2012-11-03T19:00:00-08:00
2012-11-03T19:15:00-08:00
2012-11-03T19:30:00-08:00
2012-11-03T19:45:00-08:00
2012-11-03T20:00:00-08:00
2012-11-03T20:15:00-08:00
2012-11-03T20:30:00-08:00
2012-11-03T20:45:00-08:00
2012-11-03T21:00:00-08:00
2012-11-03T21:15:00-08:00
2012-11-03T21:30:00-08:00
2012-11-03T21:45:00-08:00
2012-11-03T22:00:00-07:00
```

Comment: There are about an infinite number of ways. "What have you tried? What is the specific problem?" (c)

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: I don't really have an input. I just need to write out a bunch of them in that range like that. I am new to python... so should I just list it out and make it a dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

```
import time
print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"))
```

Comment: That includes milliseconds. The requested output shows no milliseconds.

Comment: @kichik Better?

Comment: A bit, but not what they seem to have asked for yet. There is no timezone.

Comment: @kichik Now good?

Comment: Yes, thanks. It's worth mentioning you can do the same with `datetime` objects using the `strftime()` method. It seems the question is not about the current time but rather on a range of times.

Comment: @kichik I tried doing it with `datetime`, but `datetime` prints without the timezone (for some reason)